# cannot run scons - unable to find files

Tags: anaconda, scons

So I've installed scons via Anaconda's `conda install scons` under Windows 10 (Python 3.6) and could not execute it via the command line so I've added `C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\` to my Path (even tough `C:\Users\Dominik\Anaconda3` was already in there).

Now I can execute it in the Powershell, but I get an error, because it is unable find engine files:

`scons
SCons import failed. Unable to find engine files in:
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\..\engine
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\scons-local-3.0.1
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\scons-local
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\scons-3.0.1
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scons-3.0.1
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\scons
  C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D\Anaconda3\envs\py36\Scripts\scons.py", line 192, in <module>
    import SCons.Script
ImportError: No module named 'SCons'`

Does someone know how to further investigate/fix this problem?

Comment: Likely this is a conda issue. I believe they do make some changes to SCons' setup.py for their packages.  Have you tried their mailing list or IRC channel?

Comment: Okay. Thanks you, I'll try that.

Comment: Did you `conda install scons` into a specific conda environment and if so do you `activate` that environment before running the command that produces that error? Have you tried it from the Anaconda prompt, rather than Powershell?

Comment: Thank you - this lead me to the answer. It indeed worked under the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I found it thanks to nekomatic.

If you use the anaconda prompt (with the correct environment activated or in my case the correct shortcut leading to anaconda prompt in that environment), scons runs just fine.

See [this link](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/jb5o866De3o/TNRV01YmDgAJ) explaining how anaconda uses the path on windows and whats the advantage of using the anaconda prompt (mainly it dynamically manages PATH correctly for that session only with full knowledge of conda environments).